# Debugging a hanging session/lock

Tags: postgresql, locking, transaction

We are having a recurring situation where we have 2 one query hanging, and other queries waiting for that one, and our DB grinds to a standstill. I am trying to debug this and am seeking help. The DB is RDS running Postgres 10.6.

I use DBeaver to monitor and admin this DB, and here are the screenshots from the Administer -> Lock Manager in that application. In this case, to resolve this issue, I needed to kill the one session the others are waiting on, but I would like to learn how to debug this deeper to figure out what it is waiting on, and why.

[image: The query waiting]
There are multiple copies of the above query because it is being generated by a very frequent cron job, so that is atleast expected.

[image: The query others are waiting on]
According to RDS -> Performance insights, this query, and a lot others are spending a lot of time at this point in the lock state `relation`.

I expect I havent given enough information here. Let me know what I can add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this problem, first find out what the session that blocks the others is doing:

```
SELECT state, wait_event_type, wait_event
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pid = 29303;  -- or whoever blocks the others
```

If the session is in state `active`, it is a long running query. Use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` with the query to find out where it spends its time and how to improve that.

If the state is `idle in transactions`, you have an application bug that forgot to close a transaction. Since all locks are held until the end of the transaction, this blocks other transactions even though it is doing nothing.

The short-term solution is to use the `pg_cancel_backend()` function to kill the blocking transactions.

The long-term solution is to fix bugs that keep transactions open and to improve concurrency by using fewer and less heavy locks:

The `EXCLUSIVE` lock that the transactions in your images place on a table are heavy-handed. In my experience, explicit table locks are hardly ever necessary or indicated. Usually they are a sign that the programmer doesn't understand database transactions well.

Comment: Yup, that exclusive lock based query is one that I do not like the design of, but I dont believe that it is a cause in this case, just the victim due to being the gorrila of queries.

Comment: I will keep this in mind for the next lock that happens, but given the info in the image, would you say that `28298` is the one others are waiting on? If so, we dont explicitly use transactions for that one, its just a single query

Comment: No, 28303 is the bad guy. 28298 is just a long running query that modifies data, but 28303 tries to take a lock that conflicts with that, and all others have to queue behind 28303. Without knowing `pg_locks` and the statements executed, it is impossible to say more.

Comment: 28298 is just a 1 row update, should not be a long running query. Anyway next time this happens ill try to take a dump of the pg_ tables to debug better.

Comment: Also in this particular instance, killing 28298 was enough to release the DB.

Comment: Yes. 28298 had to queue behind 28303, and the others had to queue behind it. If you kill it, the others can proceed if they don't lock with 28303.

Comment: For posterity, https://joinhandshake.com/engineering/2017/02/27/database-migrations-and-locks.html is a very detailed description of what is being explained here.

Comment: Hey, we refactored the exclusive lock away, and while we dont have that query waiting, we still have such lock ups. Could use your input at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251937/query-hanging-in-clientread-and-blocking-all-others